# Accessing a Mailbox Within An Outlook Account

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I am writing an application that will automate the sending of E-Mails from a specific mailbox within the account available on Outlook. Currently I am able to get the accounts available by doing:

```
Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts;
```

I can then iterate through the available accounts by doing:

```
foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(account.DisplayName);
}
```

My question is:
How do I **access the mailboxes within an Exchange Account** in the list. Lets say the first element in the accounts list.

I have read a few other questions on accessing the Inbox folder contents of a mailbox, but I am looking to send an email item I later create using the chosen mailbox in the "From" field.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean you need to access an Exchange mailboxe owned by another user?

Comment: No, the current user in the owner of the mailbox, but they have two to choose from within their account. So if I were to draft a new email message I have the ability to choose between two different mailboxes to send from.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by"two different mailboxes"? Different POP3/SMTP accounts?

Comment: I add the mailbox by accessing my Account Settings, selecting my email account with the type of Microsoft Exchange, then selecting more settings, then the advanced tab and adding a new Mailbox there. Using Outlook 2010

Comment: You would need to use Extended MAPI to add another (not delegate) Exchange account.

Comment: Thanks, I will give the extended MAPI a try and then get back to you. Thanks for the help @DmitryStreblechenko.